# Data retrieved from an API with angular 16 won't display

Tags: angular, http, angular-material, httprequest

I'm troubled with displaying data got from an API, i've walked through the code severally couldn't find any issue and my console is error free likewise the browser displays the pagination but without the data expected. i'm using a test API.

module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DataTableComponent } from './data-table/data-table.component';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DataTableComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTableModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpClientModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

api.service.ts  file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  private apiUrl = 'https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=50&is_json=true'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(page: number, pageSize: number): Observable<any>{
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}?page=${page}&pageSize=${pageSize}`;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

data-table.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'email'];
  dataSource: any[] = [];
  pageSize = 10;
  currentPage = 1;
  totalItems = 0;

  constructor(private apiservice: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData(): void {
    this.apiservice.getData(this.currentPage, this.pageSize).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.dataSource = data.totalItems;
      this.totalItems = data.totalItems;
    });
  }

  onPageChange(event: any): void {
    this.currentPage = event.pageIndex + 1;
    this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.loadData();
  }
  
}
```

data-table.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource] = "dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{item.email}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>

</table>

<mat-paginator
    [length]="totalItems"
    [pageSize]="pageSize"
    [pageIndex]="currentPage - 1"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 30]"
    (page)="onPageChange($event)" 
></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: you should read line by line. here is what you have. dataSource is mapped to wrong prop  
 this.dataSource = data.totalItems;
      this.totalItems = data.totalItems

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is displayed because `totalItems` is `undefined`. If you take a look at what your test API returns, you can see that it is just an array of 50 items (because you set the `size` to 50).

[image: API Response]

Basically, the data structure you receive seems to differ from what you expect.
And as `SO is full of Monkeys` pointed out you assign the `totalItems` to the `dataSource` and `totalItems` so even if you prepare the data structure correctly, there is still an issue.

To make it work with the test data:

```
  loadData(): void {
    this.apiservice.getData(this.currentPage, this.pageSize).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.dataSource = data;
      this.totalItems = data.length;
    });
  }
```

But your paging will still be ignored since the API does not support it.